# 22/GB written on disk / day without much activity

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, firefox, ssd

By the end of 2017 I purchased a new computer with a Samsung 960 Pro 512GB ssd. It runs Windows 10 Pro.
about 14 months have passed and Samsung magician reports 9.3TB written on the SSD. This sounds terribly too much for me as it translates to ~22GB day (9300 GB/420 days)

The computer is powered on ~8 hours day and most of the time (96%+) has 5 firefox windows (instances) open. I have never downloaded any movies or torrents. I have routinely (less than 30 times in total) used VS 2017 and ~10 times Android Studio.

No antivirus is running - except microsoft's own windows defender.

Now, I think that 22GB written per day is way too much for such a use. Does someone have a similar experience? Does this sound problematic to you and if so, how can I pinpoint the problem ?

I am thinking that most of the data gets written to disk by Firefox (those 5 instances are on pages with rapidly changing/updating text content and some charts - also frequently updating). Task Manager on the Details Tab reports many GB of I/O bytes written for an uptime of ~18,5 days, as you can see in the screenshot.

Or could it be that windows defender also does write a lot of stuff to disk (though it theoretically it should mostly read) ?

[image]

If the culprit is firefox, is it normal? Can I somehow make firefox write less bytes to the disk ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I had seen [this](https://www.servethehome.com/firefox-is-eating-your-ssd-here-is-how-to-fix-it/) and now [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9yxmer/firefox_is_killing_my_ssd/) but I had assumed they would have fixed this already.

Comment: @Mokubai I noticed I already have slowed way down my browser.sessionstore.interval to 1800000 (half an hour) and the restore session folder works as intended. However The constant writes I see are on places.sqlite, cookies.sqlite, and places.sqlite-wal by both firefox.exe and system process